# Production environment not fetching sql data set

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net code is not fetching data set from sql database in the production environment. The code  return no records, but the same code is working fine in the development environment. I have to feed crystal report from the fetched data set.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub GenerateReport1(sql1 As String)
    Dim crReportDocument = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
    Try
        Dim ReportName As String = "KPIEstOverallReport.rpt"

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        ds = GetDataSet(sql1)

        'ds = DataAccessHelper.DataAccess.ExecuteDataSet(DataAccessHelper.DataAccess.ConnectionString, "Usp_BMS_KPI_Estimation_Performance_Report ", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param)

        Session("dsCrstalReport") = ds
        crReportDocument.FileName = Server.MapPath("~//KPIEstOverallReport.rpt")

        crReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds)

        Session("ReportDoc") = crReportDocument

        If ds IsNot Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "ShowReport", "window.open('CrystalReportViewer.aspx?','_blank','');", True)
        Else
            lblMsg.Text = "No records found..!"
            'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "No records Found.", "alert('No records found.');", True)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to make clear: **1)** do you get "No records found..!" or you get an exception or you get no error at all (e.g. if that code is not executed at all) **2)** does your db has corresponding records on production server **3)** did you try to execute sql1 against production database?

Comment: yes, i have executed the sql procedure,this db is available in production server,all the other procedures where getting executed for the same application within some other page.and i am getting no records from the procedure at the same time , for the same database i am getting result in my local environment.and nope what to do with this....

Comment: So, do you get "No records found..!"? (see #1)

Comment: yeah i am getting "No records found"

Comment: You get that message either when ds is null or ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count=0. So this is what you should check. The above code does not provide enough information and cannot be answered here.

Comment: i am having problem not with the code.because with the same code am getting result with my application in the local environment.but returns 0 records with my application in the production environment.. where the database remains same for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not provide enough information on the issue.

If you simplify your code you will get

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
ds = GetDataSet(sql1)
If (ds IsNot Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Is False Then
    lblMsg.Text = "No records found..!"
End If
```

where you get "No records found..!" because either ds is Nothing or Tables(0) has no recods.

This could happen only when sql1 returns no records or you have an error in the GetDataSet method that could return Nothing.

To troubleshoot, you need to debug GetDataSet() and see what it does.

Comment: sorry i think am having no problem with the code now.the code is working in local environment and getting idle in production environment and thanks for your support @smirnov

Comment: got the result !!! when i convert one of the input from date type date to date time i the procedure returns the data set and thus i got my output.but still i am getting the proper result in the local environment for the old data type and thanks for the help friends.